# How can I include ladybug to magento

Tags: magento, debugging

Is there an easy way to add the ladybug debugger to magento with composer?

When I try to add to Mage.php the line:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

using the `ld($var)` is not working

Tx

Ladybug is [here](https://github.com/raulfraile/ladybug/blob/master/doc/usage.md)

Comment: this made tre trick At the top of Mage.php include this :  require 'vendor_composer/autoload.php';
 Ladybug\Loader::loadHelpers();

Answer (score 0):

this made tre trick At the top of Mage.php 
include this :

```
require 'vendor_composer/autoload.php'; 
Ladybug\Loader::loadHelpers();
```

And you can use ld($var) and ldd() now ;)

The only thing i dont like is being modify the core file :(